# How to hide all display selections in edit mode?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices

**Hello**, is it possible to hide all the ways to display selection in Edit Mode on Blender?

I've already disabled all Meshs Display Selections, but it still shows some selections.

**OBS**: I do not want to hide the vertices, but rather display the selections in edit mode.

[image]

Comment: To hide the selected vertices press H to unhide them press Alt+H

Comment: Hi, my goal is to hide only the selection pointers, not the object vertices. I think I expressed myself poorly...

Comment: Done! I hope you can understand ... I've been trying for a long time.

Comment: Maybe the only way to hide vertices' selectors is in the User Preferences > Themes > 3d View > Vertex Size slider (scroll down). It won't hide them at all but will make very small (1 px) for all the vertices available in the scene.

Comment: With your cursor in the viewport pressing "N" will hide and un-hide the panel on the far right (Pressing "T" will do the same for the panel on the left). Alternatively you can hover your cursor over the edge of the panel and click and drag it closed.

Comment: Thanks @MrZak, but unfortunately decreasing the vertex to 1 px is almost impossible to model.

Comment: @Dontwalk This is not quite the solution I need, but thank you.

Comment: I can't really imagine why would you need that when modeling as by all means it's required to trace the geometry constantly for errors, that solution was only for previewing without vertices. Note that you won't see vertices if switching to any other selection mode (e.g. Ctrl+Tab>Edges)